# How to find publications from a particular institution in a journal?

Tags: journals

Suppose now I am interested in University A and a Journal B. I want to know how many people from University A published a paper in Journal B, and what are these papers. How to do this?

Comment: The information you need is public. Faculty lists are easily found. Journal indices are easily found. It's just a bit of a search and correlation. You will get some false positives, though.

Comment: Why do you want to know this?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Some journals are top journals in some specific fields. I want to know who in University A has published many papers in the top journals so I can roughly find out the most productive researcher with high-quality papers in some fields. This can be seen as a criterion to find a good supervisor somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, affiliations are a mess. People in bibliometrics usually say that you have to know the institution and its various names, acronyms, institutes, and laboratories very well, to capture all publications from the institution. If you have this knowledge, set up a corresponding search query (advanced search) for Web of Science (you need to have access to this database via your institution) and add the journal as additional condition.

Another approach is to check whether the institution you look at has a publications database and you can search for specific journals in there.

Comment: Sometimes the journal's (or their publisher's) websites have search tools advanced enough to allow searching/filtering by affiliation too.

Comment: @Anyon That's true! Just make sure to capture all names, acronyms etc.

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics, you should be able to do this in [MathSciNet](https://mathscinet.ams.org) (subscription required).

Here is an example I did.
Ohio State University Math department, published in Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society.
  JOURNAL Proc Amer Math Soc
  INSTITUTION 1-OHS
I get 102 results.
You have to look up the codes for the items you want.  If I just put "Ohio State" for the institution I seem to get lots of things that are not matches.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use lens.org which is free, and where you can use many simultaneous conditions in order to perform the search you are talking about. It is really easy to use, so I would recommend you to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

> "I want to know how many people from University A published a paper in Journal B

I agree with the [answer by FuzzyLeapfrog](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/125491/93303) which is that "affiliations are a mess". The one thing I can add is that some publishing companies have specific tools to allow you to see and track affiliation data, for example the Nature Publishing Group has "[nature index](https://www.natureindex.com/institution-outputs/generate/all/global/all)" which among other things, gives the list of "how many people from University A published with publishing company B":

[image]

Comment: Got a downvote after my interactions with BryanKrausse and ZeroTheHero here https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/194195/93303. Had a positive score before though, and I don't see anything wrong with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Scopus search, you can do an "affiliations" search, and this often helps to know about the research achievements and research potential of an University..

[image: Scopus affiliations search]